# Upload image from as3 to instagram/facebook

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, api, flash, instagram

I'm planning to create a photo booth program using AS3. I'm searching for this questions but can't find any solution so i just want to clarify it here if it is possible or not.

My questions are:

1.It is possible to post an image from AS3 to Instagram using my account?

2.It is possible to post an image from AS3 to Facebook page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook - Yes,

https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/getting-started-with-facebooksdk-actionscript3.html

Instagram - Maybe.

I found [This](https://github.com/Khaledgarbaya/Instagras), which is a library for instagram to AS3 communication, but I am unsure on how well it handles.

You can test your code for Instagram's API [here](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/)

Comment: for the facebook page.. can also post image from as3 to a facebook fan page?

Comment: yes, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed
Scroll down to "Publishing"

Comment: is this is for AS3?? Pure AS3

Comment: well you cant use "pure" AS3, you have to use fb's API to talk to them. The adobe like above shows how to use the API, and the link shows how do certain tasks      with the api

Comment: its also working for a fan page facebook not the personal account.? When i post a picture it will post to the fan page not in my personal account... I'm quite confuse on how to do it.

Comment: You are going to have to research it yourself using the documentation provided by facebook on how to use their API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/)

Comment: i understand now...for instagram api for as3 is also available?

Comment: I believe so. You might have to use the library above since I don't believe its natively available

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check the Instagram api console here:http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/
They are listing every available api calls,after getting what you need it is a matter of using a URLLoader with URLVariables that contains all the HTTP vars the console shows and of course with the access token.
All the API is Rest .